# how to compile a python .app from ubuntu or windows

Tags: python, ubuntu, osx-snow-leopard, cx-freeze

I am still very new to Python and any freezing programs.

Recently I made a very short text adventure game I'd like to send to a few friends, most of whom have Snow Leopard. I don't want them to have to bother downloading python just to play the game though.

Is there a way to convert my game from Ubuntu so that it is playable on Mac? That is, make an .app file from ubuntu? Or even from Windows, I suppose.

I tried using cx_freeze on Windows but that just compiles an exe which is not playable on Mac.

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

EDIT: I am using Python 3.2.2. I think Macs come standard with an older version else there would be no problem just sending them the game, I imagine.

Comment: Have you tried [py2app](http://svn.pythonmac.org/py2app/py2app/trunk/doc/index.html)?

Comment: "cross-compile" is not an appropiate term since you are not "compiling" anything (Python is a interpreted language anyway), you just want to obtain (pack) a platform dependent executable that ships the required runtime environment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up regarding çompiling, phineas. As for the py2App suggestion, Brendan, it seems that py2app only claims support up to python 2.7. I am going to try anyway and see what happens, though. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to install py2app on Windows, but am having an error while trying to build the .app. It seems the version of Python I am using has issues with py2app. Are there no other ways of converting to .app? I have tried using all the google prowess I have but to no avail.

Comment: The [development version](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze) of cx_Freeze supports freezing to a Mac application on Python 3, but you still need a Mac to do it. I don't think any of the tools can produce an executable for a different platform (beyond different versions or Linux distros, I mean).

Comment: Thanks, Thoman. It is as I feared. Maybe using a Virtual Machine? I am going to experiment with that tonight and see how I fare...

Comment: Using a VM should work, although I've no idea about the legalities of getting OS X set up on a VM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, last I used Mac OSX, it already had Python installed. This was with Mac OSX Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

No need do compile to a native binary if you can run your code through Python on any machine.

Your code could run in Python 2.6, the default which comes with Snow Leaopard, unless you used version 3 specific features. Try if it does. If so just package your code so it runs the .py through `python /path/to/code.py`

You can also make your .py file self-executable with a shebang first line,

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# this should be the first line in your .py file
```

and setting the file executable flag, perhaps through your packager on installation:

```
$ chmod +x code.py
```

You will notice shebang does not point to a specific python binary like `/usr/bin/python`, but to the `/env` environment path, so it will use the default interpreter on whichever machine it is run on.

Comment: They seem to want to make it self-contained.